# running a batch file from oracle forms 6i using host

Tags: oracle, forms, batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file. the file is located here:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\getfile.bat
```

I use this in oracle forms 6i:
first i assign this path to a variable:

```
tmp_msg := 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\getfile.bat'
```

then I use the host command:

```
host( 'cmd /c' || tmp_msg, no_screen);
```

This is exactly as I have it. It doesn't give me an error, but I don't get the result that I'm expecting. I'm actually executing java code in the batch file like so: java -classpath path;addedpackage.jar myClass

I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you try it without the no_screen argument to see *something* instead of just guessing?

Comment: Yes, I tried...no better. Do i need to have any special utility attached to my form in order to use the host command you think? I even tried just running a simple DOS command through host and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the command to work. The reason it wasn't working was because the function (block) i had it in wasn't getting executed. Oracle forms are sometimes tricky. this worked: host(tmp_msg);

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need a space after /c:

```
host( 'cmd /c ' || tmp_msg, no_screen);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use command like this

```
host('cmd /c start '||filename, no_screen);
```